# Download free app updates without prompting to enter Apple ID password on iOS 6

Tags: ios-appstore, password, ios

I read somewhere in iOS 6 you don't need to enter your Apple ID password for downloading free apps and updates to already installed apps. However I see that I am still being prompted for my Apple ID password. Is there any solution for this? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I believe this only applies to updates.  Installing an app still requires you to enter your password.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions turned on? I get prompted for my password with updates in iOS6 as well, and assumed it was because of restrictions I've enabled.

Comment: No, I don't have any restrictions turned on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No password is required for app updates in iOS 6, but you still have to enter your password to buy apps, even free ones.

Comment: Yet, I still need to enter the password to update when the app was downloaded with a different Apple ID.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need an ID or password, anyone could download anything anywhere.
I would be worried if no password was required